# Get the Id of current table row with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I have the following code in a form . When the user clicks a button I want to get the current row in order to identify which of the buttons was clicked

```
<tr  id="TEST1" >
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <div align="right">Contact</div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle">
        <input type="text" id="contact1" size="20" />  Number 
        <input type="text" id="number1" size="20" /> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button"  value="Button 1" id="contact1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="TEST2" >
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <div align="right">Contact</div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle">
        <input type="text" id="contact2" size="20" />  Number 
        <input type="text" id="number2" size="20" /> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button"  value="Button 1"  id="contact2" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="TEST3" >
    <td align="left" valign="middle">
        <div align="right">Contact</div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle">
        <input type="text" id="contact3" size="20" />  Number 
        <input type="text" id="number3" size="20" /> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button"  value="Button 1"  id="contact2" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I thought the following Jquery would return the ID name but it doesn't

```
$('input[type=button]' ).click(function() {
    bid = (this.id) ; // button ID 
    trid = $('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID 
});
```

Can anyone give me some advice please ?  thanks

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get up to the current `<tr>` parent, like this:

```
$('input[type=button]' ).click(function() {
   var bid = this.id; // button ID 
   var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID 
 });
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code would be more like so:

```
$('tr input[type=button]').click(function(){
    id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
<table id="test">
      <tr  id="TEST1" >
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><div align="right">Contact</div></td>
          <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle">
          <input type="text" id="contact1" size="20" />  Number 
          <input type="text" id="number1" size="20" /> 
          </td>
          <td>
          <input type="button"  value="Button 1" id="contact1" /></td>
      </tr>


      <tr id="TEST2" >
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><div align="right">Contact</div></td>
          <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle">
          <input type="text" id="contact2" size="20" />  Number 
          <input type="text" id="number2" size="20" /> 
          </td>
          <td>
          <input type="button"  value="Button 1"  id="contact2" />
          </td> 
      </tr>

      <tr id="TEST3" >
          <td align="left" valign="middle"><div align="right">Contact</div></td>
          <td colspan="4" align="left" valign="middle">
          <input type="text" id="contact3" size="20" />  Number 
          <input type="text" id="number3" size="20" /> 
          </td>
          <td>
          <input type="button"  value="Button 1"  id="contact2" />
          </td> 
</tr>
```

and javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var bid, trid;
  $('#test tr').click(function() {
       trid = $(this).attr('id'); // table row ID 
       alert(trid);
  });
```

});

It worked here!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('input[type=button]' ).click(function() {
   var bid = jQuery(this).attr('id'); // button ID 
   var trid = $(this).parents('tr:first').attr('id'); // table row ID 
 });
```

Comment: why did you change the button ID? `this.id` should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

First, your jQuery will not work at all unless you enclose all your `tr`s and `td`s in a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>...</tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Second, your code gets the `id` of the first `tr` of the page, since you select all the `tr`s of the page and get the `id` of the first one (**[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** returns the attribute of the first element in the set of elements it is used on)

**Your current code:**

```
  $('input[type=button]' ).click(function() {
   bid = (this.id) ; // button ID 
   trid = $('tr').attr('id'); // ID of the the first TR on the page
                              // $('tr') selects all trs in the DOM
  });
```

### **[trid is always TEST1 (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/SWTy2/)**

Instead of selecting all `tr`s on the page with `$('tr')`, you want to select the first ancestor of the clicked upon `input` that is a `tr`. Use **[`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** for this in the form `$(this).closest('tr')`.

You can reference the clicked on element as `this`, make a jQuery object out of it with the form `$(this)`, so you have access to all the jQuery methods on it.

**What your code should look like:**

```
  // On DOM ready...
$(function() {

      $('input[type=button]' ).click(function() {

          var bid, trid; // Declare variables. If you don't use var 
                         // you will bind bid and trid 
                         // to the window, since you make them global variables.

          bid = (this.id) ; // button ID 

          trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID 
      });
});
```

### **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KSyB8/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled</title>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function getVal(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;

    alert(targ.innerHTML);
}

onload = function() {
    var t = document.getElementById("main").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
        t[i].onclick = getVal;
}

</script>



<body>

<table id="main"><tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a class in css name it .buttoncontact, add the class attribute to your buttons

```
function ClickedRow() {
    $(document).on('click', '.buttoncontact', function () {
        var row = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
        var rowtext = $(this).closest('tr').text();
        alert(row);      
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tblCart tr').click(function () {
        var tr_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
        alert(tr_id );
    });



<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tblCart" cellspacing="0" align="center" >
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item.ItemName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price.PriceAmount)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subtotal)
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

               @if (cart != null)
               {
                   foreach (var vm in cart)
                   {
                    <tr id="@vm.Id">
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vm.Item.ItemName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vm.Price.PriceAmount)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vm.Quantity)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => vm.Subtotal)
                        </td>
                        <td >                            
                            <span style="width:80px; text-align:center;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign" />                        
                        </td>
                    </tr>  
                   }
               }
            </table>
```